# error "No node was available to execute the query" while using MCS service of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, connection-pooling, cql

after some time we got error:

> 2020-03-30 14:09:45 +0000 [http-nio-12082-exec-10] ERROR c.i.i.c.u.c.GenericCassandraDao 2fcc2418-2a0f-401e-b51f-b57fc0b305ea -
>   Error in inserting data for tenant code: anne2020-03-30 14:09:45 +0000
>   [http-nio-12082-exec-10] ERROR c.i.i.c.u.c.GenericCassandraDao
>   2fcc2418-2a0f-401e-b51f-b57fc0b305ea - Error in inserting data for
>   tenant code:
>   annecom.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node
>   was available to execute the query at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException.copy(NoNodeAvailableException.java:40)
>   at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
>   at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
>   at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
>   at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:210)
>   at
>   com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:53)
>   at
>   us.cassandra.GenericCassandraDao.save(GenericCassandraDao.java:79)
>   at
>   us.cassandra.implementations.BasicCassandraStorage.lambda$save$0(BasicCassandraStorage.java:26)
>   at
>   io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker.lambda$decorateSupplier$4(CircuitBreaker.java:536)
>   at
>   us.cassandra.implementations.CircuitBreakerStorage.wrap(CircuitBreakerStorage.java:34)

Restart helps but its not the solution. Appreciate if anyone can help me find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute nodetool status in cassandra and you will obtain the name of the Datacenter.

...**$ ./nodetool status**

Then,
Change .withLocalDatacenter("us-east-1") to .withLocalDatacenter("your-data-center-name") and retry.

Kindly follow this link = https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mcs/latest/devguide/ManagedCassandraService.pdf